# VIP Ticket in Grim Fandango?

Tags: grim-fandango

I am playing Grim Fandango Remastered and I am trying to get the VIP ticket at the cat races.

I have talked to Charlie already, but do not have a VIP ticket. Is there something I need to do to get additional speech options? When I try to talk to him now, it says "I have nothing to say to him".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to get the VIP pass to the high roller's lounge, you need to ask him to make a counterfeit Union Card that you will need to get out of Rubacava.  In return, he will ask you to retrieve his briefcase that you'll need the pass to enter the lounge.

Make sure you speak to Dock Master Velasco to learn about how to get out of Rubacava to follow Meche.  He will tell you about the requirements to ride on the S.S. Lambada after you offer your services (and Glottis) to work on the ship.

1. Glottis needs tools to be the engineer.
2. The ship out is full but there's a chance that you can take place of Seaman Naranja.
3. You must be in the union by having a Union Card.

But of course before Manny can ask him about the counterfeit cards, you'll have to know that he can make them.  Make sure you speak with Chowchilla Charlie until he pulls out his betting stub maker which you will then confiscate.  That will give you the option to ask him what else he can counterfeit.  The Union Card will be an option once you know to ask.

Comment: Yes, talking to Velasco is the trigger here, thanks!